# How to correctly obtain coordinates from Open Layers v4.2, API when regions repeat

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

How to correctly obtain coordinates from map when countries repeat, i.e when we zoom out to maximum, countries repeat and clicking on same country gives invalid coordinates. We cannot restrict the user by showing a single world map (this can be done by setting up the WrapX property). Any other solution , Please help.

Adding sample code which displays coordinates. Please hover the mouse over same country/region which repeats and see difference.

```js
"use strict";
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  wrapX: false
});


/*Layer Styles*/

var stylesIcon = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon({
    anchor: [0.5, 46],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
    opacity: 0.75,
    src: 'icon.png'
  })
})

var stylesIcon2 = new ol.style.Style({
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'rgba(0,0,255,0.3)'
  }),
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: '#000100',
    width: 2
  }),
  image: new ol.style.Circle({
    radius: 7,
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: '#000000'
    })
  })
})


/*Layers*/

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: stylesIcon
});

/*Map*/

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM({})
  }), vectorLayer],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0]),
    zoom: 1
  })
});

var element = document.getElementById('popup');
element.onmouseout = function(event) {
  element.style.visibility = 'hidden'
};

var popup = new ol.Overlay({
  element: element,
  positioning: 'bottom-center',
  stopEvent: false
});

map.addOverlay(popup);

/*Events*/

map.on("pointermove", function(event) {

  var lonlat = ol.proj.transform(event.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857',
    'EPSG:4326');
  var logitude = lonlat[0];
  var lattitude = lonlat[1];

  document.getElementById('mousePointer').innerText = 'longitude : ' +
    logitude + ' latitude : ' + lattitude;
});

map.on("singleclick", function(event) {
  var lonlat = ol.proj.transform(event.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857',
    'EPSG:4326');

  var logitude = lonlat[0];
  var lattitude = lonlat[1];

  document.getElementById('mouseClick').innerText = 'longitude : ' +
    logitude + ' latitude : ' + lattitude;
});

map.on('click', function(event) {
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function(
    feature, layer) {
    return feature;
  })
  if (feature) {
    var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
    var coord = geometry.getCoordinates();
    popup.setPosition(coord);

    var element = document.getElementById('popup');
    element.innerText = feature.get('name')
    element.style.visibility = 'visible'
  }
})

function createMarkers() {
  var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById('latitudeInp').value);
  var lng = parseFloat(document.getElementById('logitudeInp').value);

  vectorSource.clear();
  vectorSource.addFeature(new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lng, lat],
      'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
    name: 'Added Marker'
  }));

}
```

```css
a.skiplink {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a.skiplink:focus {
  clip: auto;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0.3em;
}

#map:focus {
  outline: #4A74A8 solid 0.15em;
}

.mapDemo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Accessible Map</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet -->
  <!-- Explorer and Android 4.x -->
  <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
  <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/build/ol.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <a class="skiplink" href="#map">Go to map</a>
  <div id="map" class="map" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div id="mapDemo" class="mapDemo">
    <h3>Demo Actions</h3>
    <p>
      Current mouse pointer : <span id="mousePointer"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
      Clicked at :<span id="mouseClick"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
      Add Marker : <span>
                <label>Longitude : </label><input type="number" id="logitudeInp" />
            </span> <span>
                <label>
                    Latitude
                    :
                </label><input type="number" id="latitudeInp" />
            </span> <span>
                <label>
                    Name
                    :
                </label><input type="text" id="nameInp" />
            </span> <span>
                <label>
                    Submit
                    :
                </label><input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="createMarkers()" />
            </span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="popup"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set wrapX: false on your tile source.

```
 new ol.layer.Tile({
   source: new ol.source.OSM({
    wrapX: false
  })
})
```

Comment: the map end on sides , I have mentioned this point in question